# Run two X servers using a single GPU

Tags: ubuntu, x11

I wrote a X11 proxy server program that allows to send "faked" input events to an X11 client. First, I have to start the proxy server and then I can start my client program with
`export DISPLAY=:2 myClientProgram`. The proxy server will then pass messages from *myClientProgram* to the default X11 server and vice-versa and inject faked input messages on request.

The problem is that whenever I inject a faked input message, *myClientProgram* requests input focus. This makes it impossible for me to use the computer for other activities. Imagine trying to write something when loosing input focus all the time, it's impossible.

I tried already to understand if there is a solution to prevent *myClientProgam* from getting input focus. My current understanding is that there is none. Hence, I'd like to pursue a new different approach.

Is there a way such that I can run two X11 servers on single machine and be able two switch between them? If the solution would use something like `Xephyr`, it would be important that the *main* X server does **not** use the GPU. *myClientProgram* needs my Nvidia graphics card and I have only one. It would be completely fine if the X server that I use to do my usual work (browsing the web, coding, writing documents, etc.) uses llvmpipe.

To be specific, it is important that if I was to open a terminal using the X server that is to run *myClientProgam*, then `glxinfo` must return my graphics card as the rendering device.

Comment: To better understand your question: I once isolated a robot that simulated user interaction with an 3d party application Y, by running inside a VM. In the VM, Y had the focus, and the robot scrolled through it, filled out text input fields and copied its output to a file, while I on the VM host could continue with my daily work. Is that the kind of problem you want to solve by running your client program on DISPLAY 2? And for what reason can you not run it inside a VM?

Comment: This would be exactly what I want to do. Which VM did you use? I have only experience with VirtualBox and to the best of my knowledge, I can't access the GPU. *myClientProgram* is using PyTorch and CUDA.

Comment: I see, that is why you need the GPU so bad. VirtualBox, which I used, is indeed not suited for your purpose. My example needed only the generic graphics card.

Comment: If your need of the physical GPU is only for making calculations, and as you wrote your client program yourself, maybe there is a solution in splitting up that program. If you isolate the robot and it's focussing stuff in a VM, you can delegate the calculations to the VM host. There are different ways of communicating between VM and VM host: through a file, through the virtual network, and there even are some VirtualBox commands for direct interaction. My only experience with this, is GPU-assisted video compression through ffmpeg, and it does not interfere with what is displayed on your screen